# UE4 How to load level in commandlet?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I want to log all actors in level with commandlet, so I wrote the code like this.

```cpp
#include "MyCommandlet.h"
#include "Kismet/GameplayStatics.h"
#include "Engine/StaticMeshActor.h"
#include "MyCharacter.h"

int32 UMyCommandlet::Main(const FString& Params)
{
    TArray<AActor*> arrActors;
    UWorld* World = GetWorld();

    if (World)
    {
        UGameplayStatics::GetAllActorsOfClass(GetWorld(), AMyCharacter::StaticClass(), arrActors);

        for (int i = 0; i < arrActors.Num(); i++)
        {
            AMyCharacter* pCharacter = dynamic_cast<AMyCharacter*>(arrActors[i]);

            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Display, TEXT("%d"), pCharacter->TestValue);

        }   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But GetWorld() returns NULL. I thouht the reason is that when commandlet is called, there are no levels loaded.

Actually Unreal Engine document says
"Commandlets are executed in a "raw" environment, in which the game isn't loaded, the client code isn't loaded, no levels are loaded, and no actors exist."
LINK: [https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Commandlets/UCommandlet/#:~:text=UCommandlet%20%3A%20public%20UObject-,Remarks,-Commandlet%20](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Commandlets/UCommandlet/#:%7E:text=UCommandlet%20%3A%20public%20UObject-,Remarks,-Commandlet%20)

Then how can I load level or getworld() in commandlet...??

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the `UImportAssetsCommandlet::LoadLevel` in`Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\Commandlets\ImportAssetsCommandlet.cpp`. It manually loads the `umap` and initializes the `UWorld`:

```cpp
bool UImportAssetsCommandlet::LoadLevel(const FString& LevelToLoad)
{
    bool bResult = false;

    if (!LevelToLoad.IsEmpty())
    {
        UE_LOG(LogAutomatedImport, Log, TEXT("Loading Map %s"), *LevelToLoad);

        FString Filename;
        if (FPackageName::TryConvertLongPackageNameToFilename(LevelToLoad, Filename))
        {
            UPackage* Package = LoadPackage(NULL, *Filename, 0);

            UWorld* World = UWorld::FindWorldInPackage(Package);
            if (World)
            {
                // Clean up any previous world.  The world should have already been saved
                UWorld* ExistingWorld = GEditor->GetEditorWorldContext().World();

                GEngine->DestroyWorldContext(ExistingWorld);
                ExistingWorld->DestroyWorld(true, World);

                GWorld = World;

                World->WorldType = EWorldType::Editor;

                FWorldContext& WorldContext = GEngine->CreateNewWorldContext(World->WorldType);
                WorldContext.SetCurrentWorld(World);

                // add the world to the root set so that the garbage collection to delete replaced actors doesn't garbage collect the whole world
                World->AddToRoot();

                // initialize the levels in the world
                World->InitWorld(UWorld::InitializationValues().AllowAudioPlayback(false));
                World->GetWorldSettings()->PostEditChange();
                World->UpdateWorldComponents(true, false);

                bResult = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // a map was not specified, ignore
        bResult = true;
    }

    if (!bResult)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogAutomatedImport, Error, TEXT("Could not find or load level %s"), *LevelToLoad);
    }

    return bResult;

}
```

Then use the `TActorIterator` to log out the `Actor`:

```cpp
    if (World)
    {
        int32 ActorCount = 0;
        for (TActorIterator<AActor> It(World); It; ++It)
        {
            AActor* CurrentActor = *It;
            FString ActorName = CurrentActor->GetName();

            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Actor: %s"), *ActorName);
            ActorCount++;
        }

        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Total number of actors: %d"), ActorCount);
    }
    else
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Error, TEXT("Failed to load the specified map."));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
FString levelAssetPath = TEXT("/Game/Maps/SomeLevel");
GEditor->GetEditorSubsystem<ULevelEditorSubsystem>()->LoadLevel(levelAssetPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create a FAutoConsoleCommandWithWorldAndArgs to bind your function, it'll pass in a UWorld.

```
FAutoConsoleCommandWithWorldAndArgs AbilitySystemToggleDebugHUDCommand(
TEXT("Your Command"),
TEXT("Your Help Text"),
FConsoleCommandWithWorldAndArgsDelegate::CreateStatic(Your_Function)
);

static void Your_Function(const TArray<FString>& Args, UWorld* InWorld);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This world should not be NULL in a commandlet:

`UWorld* World = GEditor->GetEditorWorldContext().World();`